# Fisher's information of normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, expectation

Give a sample $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n $~$N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $\sigma^2=1$. I want to find Fisher's information. I know that:
$$
-E(\frac{d^2}{d\mu^2} \ln f(x))=1/\sigma^2.
$$ 
Why this is the Fisher's information in this case? Why the second derivative of normal distribution is not simply equal to zero as expectation of $X$ is $\mu$?

Comment: If the parameter is $\mu$, $\ln f(x;\mu)=const-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$. The second derivation is not zero but simply $-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}$.

Comment: Yes, we treat $\mu$ as parameter. OK but if we expand the top of the fraction after derivative we are left with $X-\mu$ which should be equal to 0? Could you explain that further?

Comment: Take the second derivative of $-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}$; how do you end up with $X-\mu$?

Comment: It shouldn't be a second derivative of normal distribution  PDF? If not than i understand the reason why however i thought that it is about second derivative of PDF function.

Comment: its logarithm: $\ln f(x)$

Comment: OK, fine. My mistake